# Materials doesn't applying in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm playing with Unity3d and materials don't load or apply to models in the editor for some reason

sample image:

[image]

Specs:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Unity3d 2018.1.08b

What can it be?

Comment: How are you currently trying to apply the material on the model? What is happening compared to what you expect to happen? We need more details.

Comment: You mean by load is that you created it on some modeling software? If it is the case how did you export your model?

Comment: I mean if I'm loading models that were created externally I get situation like on screenshot. On the screenshot above its pack from unity store, and I tried with simple model from blender exported as fbx, same situation.

Comment: it looks like the textures are missing, expand the material component in the inspector, and screenshot that. There should be at least one texture in albedo slot.

Answer (score 0):

This happen also with me. After that I applied materials to model one by one in unity. Its because when unity import model then not have correct information of materials. This is 3d designer end problem so he can fix this.
In Unity Material Naming setting effect this you can change this in Model View. Model materials name must match your naming setting to correctly import in unity.

[See Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QMAR.png)